# How to Update a mysql table using jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, mysql-connector

I need to update from a jsp page a field into a mysql table.

I used this code:

```
int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("r"));

    switch(id)
    {
        case 0:
            ruolo="null";
            break;
        case 1:
            ruolo="Direttore";
            break;
        case 2:
            ruolo="Operaio";
            break;
        case 3:
            ruolo="Capo Reparto";
            break;
    }


    query="UPDATE dipendenti SET ruolo=? WHERE ID_dipendente="+caratteristiche[1]+"";
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    statement=connessione.prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setString(1,ruolo);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    out.println("Successfully Updating Ruolo");
```

It doesn't give me errors but the table wasn't update.

```
caratteristiche[1]
```

is a String and is referred to the ID_dipendente.

What is wrong?

Comment: try using single quotes on the WHERE ID_dipendente='+caratteristiche[1]+'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`statement.executeUpdate()` returns the number of affected records. You should check if the return value meets your expectation.

```
 int count = statement.executeUpdate();
 if (count != 1) // assuming one record should be updated
       ... // handle or log the error
```

Now since you are already using a `PreparedStatement` you should also use a parameter for the the `ID_dipendente` param:

```
query="UPDATE dipendenti SET ruolo=? WHERE ID_dipendente=?";
PreparedStatement statement = null;
statement=connessione.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setString(1,ruolo);
statement.setString(2,caratteristiche[1]);
int count = statement.executeUpdate();
```